# angular routing, there's an error "injector:modulerr", can't find my ng-app

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm new to angular js...I just want to load the html file when clicking on the link it's pertaining to. But it's throwing an error saying It can't find my ng-app directive. I edited the templateUrl objects to load some cat photos...but still no go.

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/skills", {
        templateUrl : "https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fkittentoob.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2018%2F01%2FA-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg&f=1"
    })
    .when("/interactives", {
        templateUrl : "https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.PRniL4_JLNvVMzdVgiDiYgHaEK%26pid%3D15.1&f=1"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div class="row"> 
  <div class="float-left p-5">
   <nav>
    <a class="mr-3 menu2" href="#!skills">Skill Set</a>
    <a class="mr-3 menu3" href="#!interactives">Interactives</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="h-75">
  <div class="middle">
   <div ng-view>
    <!-- body -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you loading the script you shared in the HTML you shared? The HTML you shared doesn't have any `<script>` loading the AngularJS code you shared in your question.

Comment: I took it out for the purpose of the snippet. Went ahead and added it back...